# Importing Excel Spreadsheet Into SQL Database (Coldfusion 9)

Tags: sql, excel, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm writing a script to import a large excel spreadhseet into an SQL Server 2008 database. Everything is working fine except for one minor detail:

If a cell in the sheet has multiple options (like a `<select>` dropdown menu), only the selected option gets grabbed. I want to grab every possible option the cell has, not just the one being used (See my SQL query for why)

I have searched google and S/O for answers but I have not encountered a solution for this particular situation. [Here is a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20161122041233/http://help.adobe.com:80/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSaad0660b0585370c-3b13488c12d7e9aabe0-8000) to the Spreadsheet Functions I am using.

I cannot show you the excel sheet, but it is safe to assume the traversing of the sheet is correct (I have tested it).

Here is my code:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="spreadsheet.xlsx" name="sheet">
<cfoutput>
    #sheet.rowcount-3#
<cfloop from="2" to="#sheet.rowcount-3#" index="row">
    <cfquery datasource="Questions" result="rState">
        INSERT INTO States
        (
            State,
            StateAbbr
        )
        VALUES 
        (
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#SpreadsheetGetCellValue(sheet,row,1)#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#SpreadsheetGetCellValue(sheet,row,2)#">
        )
    </cfquery>
    #SpreadsheetGetCellValue(sheet,row,1)#<br />
    #SpreadsheetGetCellValue(sheet,row,2)#<br />
    <cfloop from="3" to="15" index="col"> <!--- multi row selection (edit based on excel sheet col relationship) --->
        <cfif SpreadsheetGetCellValue(sheet,row,col) EQ "">
            <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sheet,"N/A",row,col) />
        </cfif>
        <cfquery datasource="Questions" result="rResponse">
            IF NOT EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT Response
                FROM Responses
                WHERE Response=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar" value="#SpreadsheetGetCellValue(sheet,row,col)#">
            )
            INSERT INTO Responses
            (
                Response
            )
            VALUES
            (
                <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar" value="#SpreadsheetGetCellValue(sheet,row,col)#">
            )
        </cfquery>
        #row#X#col#<br />
        #SpreadsheetGetCellValue(sheet,row,col)#<br />
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Edit: I cannot show the excel sheet I'm using, but I recreated the list so you know what sort of drop down cell I am talking about. NOTE: The sheet I'm using, the options list was NOT built with cells, the creator used static values in the validation clause!!!

[image]

Comment: (Edit) Not sure I follow. Why do you need options that were not selected? Or is the problem that the spreadsheet functions are not returning *all* of the selected options? AFAIK, there are no CF functions that can do this. [This thread](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Read-drop-down-list-data-td4574232.html) suggests there nothing built into POI either. At least for xls sheets. There are different types of lists in Excel, so we really need to see a sample. Can you upload a *sanitized* file or sample? We could play around with it and maybe someone could come up with a solution.

Comment: I edited my question with a small screenshot of the drop down style (It's not related to the data in the sheet I'm using, but it's the exact same style). Basically each cell I'm traversing has a "Response" so I'm importing each possible response with a unique ID so they can be re-used.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the data values that are used for the list in Excel have to come from other Excel fields. These can be contained somewhere else in the same spreadsheet or another spreadsheet altogether.  Where is the data stored for your list(s)? Can you access those cells via `SpreadsheetGetCellValue()` instead?

Comment: @Miguel-F - I think you are right, but the question is how to access the location info with CF.  RUJordan - Maybe I am being obtuse, but you are already ensuring unique ID's with the `IF NOT EXISTS...` part. So I am still not clear about the answer to my earlier question: *Why do you need options that were not selected? Or is the problem that the spreadsheet functions are not returning all of the selected options?*

Comment: @Leigh - good questions. In my mind CF is working as designed here. The "list" cell basically contains a formula. No different than if the cell contained the formula `Sum(B1,B2)` then CF would return the formula's _result_ (the sum) not the numbers that generated the result. Perhaps the OP could use the `SpreadsheetGetCellFormula()` function to dynamically retrieve the cells used to populate the list? Not sure as I have not used that before. Anyway more clarification is needed for this one.

Comment: @Leigh I need the unused options simply because they are options (they will be used in the future with more spreadsheets to come. I used multiple cells as an example, and that was a mistake -- they are defined within the spreadsheet validation option, not within the sheet itself. So in this case, there isn't a formula (which is quite frustrating..), and it would be a nightmare to make a formula for thousands of cell options. Just to clarify, all selected options are imported perfectly. It's the unselected options in this case

Comment: @RUJordan - Then you probably have to resort to using java/POI. Something like [the method mentioned here (xlsx only)](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Read-drop-down-list-data-td4574232.html). Not sure if it works, but it is worth a shot. I cannot test it until later, when I am near a machine with the right version of Excel.

Comment: @Leigh I'll look into that -- thanks for the link. It's interesting, Coldfusion makes reading spreadsheets so easy except for apparently this. Haha..

Comment: @RUJordan - Haha, unfortunately there are a bunch of things you can only do with POI ;-) .. but at least its accessible.

Comment: Have you tried importing it into the database first VIA the MSSQL import tool? I'm not sure if it will read the drop down function but it might be worth a shot. Or how about using the excel sheet as a datasource?

Comment: @CoryFail it needs to grab the drop down list (all of it, even unused optiosn). EVERYTHING else works 100% fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got a chance to test this, and [the thread from the POI list](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Read-drop-down-list-data-td4574232.html) was spot on. Just read in the file, extract the underlying POI sheet, then grab the list of validators from the sheet object. Once you have the list of validators, loop through it and extract the options for each one.

Each validator contains a "list" of allowed options, as well as the range(s) of any cells using that rule. Note: The cell ranges are represented as objects, so you must do a little parsing to get them into a usable format.

This example returns an array of structures. Each element represents a "LIST" validator, and contains the keys:

- **list**  -  Array containing the allowed options: `["dog", "cat", ...]`
- **cells** -  Array of cell ranges ie  `{ startCell = A1, endCell = A10 }`

**Code:**

```
 <cfscript>
    // read in file and grab POI sheet
    path     = "c:/path/to/file.xlsx";
    workbook = spreadSheetRead( path ).getWorkBook();
    poiSheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");

    // extract all validators and types
    results = [];
    allRules = poiSheet.getDataValidations();
    ruleTypes = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataValidationConstraint$ValidationType");

    // search all validators for "LIST" type    
    for (rule in allRules ) {

        // determine the rule type
        constraint = rule.getValidationConstraint();
        type = constraint.getValidationType();

        // if "LIST" type, grab the values and cell locations
        if (type == ruleTypes.LIST) {

            // convert address objects into strings
            ranges    = [];
            addresses = rule.getRegions().getCellRangeAddresses();

            for (i = 1; i < arrayLen(addresses); i++) {

                // extract start/end cell
                addrString = addresses[ i ];
                startCell   = listFirst( addrString, ":");  
                endCell     = listLast( addrString, ":");

                // store results
                arrayAppend( ranges, { startCell=startCell, endCell=endCell } );
            }

            // grab list values         
            values    = constraint.getExplicitListValues();

            // store results
            arrayAppend( results, { list=values, cells=ranges } );
        }
   }

   // display results   
   writeDump(results);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Inside of a `<cfscript>` could I set those variables using `<cfset>`? I just tested this as well, and it's perfect. Thank you so much, a well deserved bounty! (in 2 hours)

Comment: Not inside it, no. But you could re-write it in cfml, if you prefer. When translating java, I tend to stick with cfscript because the syntax is nearly identical. But that is just personal preference.